XML data created by pytesseract does not show elements
I created an xml file with pytesseract in the following way:
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

import pytesseract

xml = pytesseract.image_to_alto_xml("test.png")

root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for string_element in root.iter("String"):
    print(string_element.attrib)

The created xml content should find some elements, but does not.
According link ElementTree Doc I modified my code like this:
data_context = """<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<alto xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v3#" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v3# http://www.loc.gov/alto/v3/alto-3-0.xsd">
    <Description>
        <MeasurementUnit>pixel</MeasurementUnit>
        <sourceImageInformation>
            <fileName></fileName>
        </sourceImageInformation>
        <OCRProcessing ID="OCR_0">
            <ocrProcessingStep>
                <processingSoftware>
                    <softwareName>tesseract 4.1.1</softwareName>
                </processingSoftware>
            </ocrProcessingStep>
        </OCRProcessing>
    </Description>
    <Layout>
        <Page WIDTH="1016" HEIGHT="1020" PHYSICAL_IMG_NR="0" ID="page_0">
            <PrintSpace HPOS="0" VPOS="0" WIDTH="1016" HEIGHT="1020">
                <ComposedBlock ID="cblock_0" HPOS="982" VPOS="46" WIDTH="13" HEIGHT="950">
                    <TextBlock ID="block_0" HPOS="982" VPOS="46" WIDTH="13" HEIGHT="950">
                        <TextLine ID="line_0" HPOS="982" VPOS="46" WIDTH="13" HEIGHT="950">
                            <String ID="string_0" HPOS="982" VPOS="46" WIDTH="13" HEIGHT="950" WC="0.95" CONTENT=" "/>
                        </TextLine>
                    </TextBlock>
                </ComposedBlock>
                <ComposedBlock ID="cblock_35" HPOS="26" VPOS="985" WIDTH="966" HEIGHT="34">
                    <TextBlock ID="block_35" HPOS="26" VPOS="985" WIDTH="966" HEIGHT="34">
                        <TextLine ID="line_40" HPOS="26" VPOS="985" WIDTH="966" HEIGHT="34">
                            <String ID="string_40" HPOS="26" VPOS="985" WIDTH="966" HEIGHT="34" WC="0.95" CONTENT=" "/>
                        </TextLine>
                    </TextBlock>
                </ComposedBlock>
            </PrintSpace>
        </Page>
    </Layout>
</alto>
"""

root = ET.fromstring(data_context)
for string_elem in root.iter("String"):
    print(string_elem.attrib)

print("What's wrong here?")


Still the same. No elements found. What's wrong here?
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Blockquote


Found the solution: It's a namespace problem.
If I do:
alto_ns = {"alto_ns": "http://www.loc.gov/standards/alto/ns-v3#"}

root = ET.fromstring(data_context)
for string_elem in root.iterfind(".//alto_ns:String", alto_ns):
    print(string_elem.attrib)

it  works
